# how to append new element to key value pair in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, key, key-value

i have a key value pair   that contains key string and [issueFieldModal] array
so i have a object element which has e tab name and  elementArray element has a key and value property

```
var keyValuePair = KeyValuePairs<String, [ISSUEFieldModal]>()
var issueFieldArray = [ISSUEFieldModal]()
for element in elements {
 for newElement in element{
  let issueField = ISSUEFieldModal(newElement.key, newElement.value)
  issueFieldArray.append(issueField)
  }
 keyValuePair = [element.tabName: issueFieldArray]
}
```

but when i print it out the key value pair only the last  appending  shows up
i think it override the old values and set  in every loop

thank you

Comment: Because you always set `keyValuePair = [element.tabName: issueFieldArray]` in the for loop. You probably want to do sth like: `keyValuePair[element.tabName] = issueFieldArray`.

Comment: This should be as an answer.

Comment: @AndrewVergunov I don't think so considering that there is no way to set a key value pair element through subscript

Comment: @LoVo i think  you cant not  subscript like key value pairs like that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue there is that `KeyValuePairs` unlike a regular dictionary, doesn't conform to `Hashable`. You cannot assign through subscript. You may have duplicated key/value pairs. It conforms to `RandomAccessCollection` so through subscript you can only get but not set a value.

`keyValuePair = [element.tabName: issueFieldArray]` works because `KeyValuePairs` conform to `ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral` but you can NOT append a new key value pair because it doesn't conform to `RangeReplaceableCollection`. In other words you need to add all key value pairs when initialising your collection.

Comment: Does it mean we cannot remove an element from it as well?

Comment: Yes you can NOT remove an element either. [`remove(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection/3018268-remove) is only available if the collection conforms to `RangeReplaceableCollection`